# Bind Objective-C code to C# (Monotouch). Multiple protocol inheritance

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I am beginner with Objective-C. So I write my app using C# + Monotouch. Now I need to use third-party library TTTAttributedLabel written in ObjC. It is neccessary to bind it's code to C#. There is some interesting construction:

```
@protocol TTTAttributedLabel <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, copy) id text;
@end

@interface TTTAttributedLabel : UILabel <TTTAttributedLabel, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
/* some code here */
@end
```

It is clear to me about TTTAttributedLabel and UILabel inheritance. I did it this way:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface TTTAttributedLabel{
     // code here
}

[BaseType (typeof (UILabel))]
interface UITextField : TTTAttributedLabel{
}
```

But I don't know how to inherite *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate*, because in Objective-C it is a protocol but in Monotouch it is a class. So I can not inherite interface from class.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: DO You have TTTAttributed label bind project?? I need it, can you give link to git repository?

Comment: I open sourced my TTTAttributedLabel bindings that you can use - https://github.com/lipka/MonoTouch.TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, what the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate means is that the object will conform to the protocol, and as you noticed, we mapped protocols to classes which prevents this from working.

But at the core what this does is allow instance sof TTTAttributedLabel to be passed to a UIGestureRecognizer's Delegate property.

For these cases, you can instead use the WeakDelegate, which will not perform C#-level type checking and allow you to assign the instance of TTTAttributedLabel to a UIGestureRecognizer.WeakDelegate property.